# Cast UInt32 to Int Swift 3

Tags: swift, random, int

I have tried this option after having searched but it does not work, the app falls

```
let randInt:Int = Int(arc4random())
```

Help me please.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally was easy.

```
let randInt:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(inputArray.count)))
```